# Problems drawing text (strings)

Tags: java, lwjgl

I'm having a problem that, when I draw a text and call the "callGl()" method from InitGl class, it doesn't draw anything in the screen, and if I don't call it and draw, for example, a text "play" in the screen, it always shows some sort of "background" in the same color that I put (color.white, for example). What am I doing wrong?

#### Code sample

## GL CLASS

```
public class InitGl {
    public void InittGl(int Width, int Height) {
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);        
        glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);                    

        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);                
        glClearDepth(1);                                       

        glEnable(GL_BLEND);
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

        glViewport(0,0,Width, Height);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(0, Width, Height, 0, 1, -1);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
    }

    public void callGl() {
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);
        glClearDepth(1.0f);
        glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    } //This is for the render thing
}
```

#### Where I call it

## MENU CLASS

```
public class Menu {
    Words p = new Words();

    public void setWords() {
        p.setWords("Comic Sans", 24, false);
    }

    public void Update() {
        p.renderWord("PLAY", 10, 20);
    }
}
```

## SCREEN ADM CLASS WITH CALLGL

```
public class Screen {
    private InitGl in = new InitGl();
    private Menu m;
    private int numNull = 0; //Just an example

    public Screen () {
        m = new Menu();
    }

    public void Menu() {
        if (numNull == 0) {
        in.InittGl(800, 600); //It gets the screen size
        m.setWords();
        numNull = 1;
        }

        m.Update();
    }

    public void Render() {
        in.callGL();
        m.Render(in);
    }
}
```

## SCREEN ADM CLASS WITHOUT CALLGL

```
public class Screen {
    private InitGl in = new InitGl();
    private Menu m;
    private int numNull = 0; //Just an example

    public Screen () {
        m = new Menu();
    }

    public void Menu() {
        if (numNull == 0) {
        in.InittGl(800, 600); //It gets the screen size
        m.setWords();
        numNull = 1;
        }

        m.Update();
    }

    public void Render() {
        m.Render(in);
    }
}
```

## WORDS CLASS

```
public class Words {
    public TrueTypeFont font;
    public Font awtFont;

    public void setWords(String type, int size, boolean antiAliazing) {
        awtFont = new Font(type, Font.BOLD, size);
        font = new TrueTypeFont(awtFont, antiAliazing);
    }

    public void renderWord(String phrase, int x, int y) {
        font.drawString(x, y, phrase, Color.white);
    }
}
```

### Pictures

- First one is what I get when I use CallGL
- Second one is what I get when I do not use CallGL

[image: With CallGL]

[image: Without CallGL]

Comment: In the `WORDS CLASS`, are you always invoking `setWords()` before `renderWord`?  If not, the `font` might throw `NullPointerException`

Comment: Yes, I am.
In the Screen class, you can see the "m.setWords()" and "m.update()", where you have inside, respectively, "p.setWords()" and "p.renderWord()". And, just answering, no, I'm not getting nullpointer, I just get some random black screen, and don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first call `callGl()` then draw your frame... because if you draw anything before using `glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);` then you will get a black screen :)

try to put `m.Update();` inside render method.... because you need to render your text in every frame... not just once ;)

`public void Render() {
        in.callGL(); // <-------- prepare new frame
        m.Update() // <-------- draw the text in the new frame
        m.Render(in);
    }`

and what does `m.Render(in);` mean? I can't see a that method in Menu class

Comment: Oh, now it worked. Thank you very much! I didn't realized before that I was calling glClear after drawing my frame.

Comment: no problem, feel free to accept the answer ;) and ask anything you want about openGL, because I enjoy working with it :)